# how to open camera with qr code scanner?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-canvas, zxing

I have an applicaton and on its main activity there is a button, clicking on which opens a fragment at the center of the screen.
I have working code which opens camera at center as explained but  I want that simple camera view to change into qr scanner.I now have added zxing library dependency. and how to make it work when opening camera? can't arrange code. (in oncreate view) .
Any help would be great please.

```
//method in scan.java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);

        if(checkCameraHardware(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
zXingScannerView  = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            //zXingScannerView.startCamera(); I tried something like this

            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
           params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);


            //container.addView(mPreview);--->Remove this line
            //Add this line

            FrameLayout preview =(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
```

```html
//fragment_scan.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    tools:context="layout.scan"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"

    >
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    >


    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You may find this [link](https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/qr-code-android-using-zxing-library/) useful.

Comment: you can change CameraConfigurationUtils file in zxing library

Answer (score 0):

I have Button to scan qr code and access the contact number.

```
    contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enable = "contacts";
            pickBankData(enable);
        }
    });
 private void pickBankData(String val) {

 if (enable.equals("scanqr")) {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan a Qrcode");
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
        integrator.initiateScan();          //  accno.setEnabled(false);
        // ifsc.setEnabled(false);

    } }
```

and in the onactivity result the value is parsed.

```
 switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            final String result = scanResult.getContents();
            if (result != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //  tx.setText(result);
                        try {
                            String qrInputText = result;
                            String[] array = qrInputText.split(":", -1);
                            String usertype = array[0];
                            String mobilenumber = array[1];

                            String MMid = array[2];
                            String Name = array[3];
                            if (mobilenumber.equals("")) {

                            }
                            if (enable.equals("scanqr")) {
                                nameedit.setText(Name);
                                mobnum.setText(mobilenumber);

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nimra better you can use custom Lib, for qr code scaning lot of new lib found in github, Use QReader Lib simple and best.

[QReaderLib Github Link](https://github.com/nisrulz/qreader)

Implementation,

In Gradle,

```
compile 'com.github.nisrulz:qreader:{latest version}'//start from 1.0.4 version
```

Add a SurfaceView to your layout

```
  <SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/camera_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_above="@+id/info"
  />
```

Setup SurfaceView and QREader in onCreate()

```
 // QREader
private SurfaceView mySurfaceView;
private QREader qrEader;
..

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ..
  ..

  // Setup SurfaceView
  // -----------------
  mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

  // Init QREader
  // ------------
  qrEader = new QREader.Builder(this, mySurfaceView, new QRDataListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDetected(final String data) {
      Log.d("QREader", "Value : " + data);
      text.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          text.setText(data);
        }
      });
    }
  }).facing(QREader.BACK_CAM)
      .enableAutofocus(true)
      .height(mySurfaceView.getHeight())
      .width(mySurfaceView.getWidth())
      .build();

}
```

Comment: i think you nt add library in your dependices,

Comment: I have added the dependency which u pasted here. In my gradle

Comment: ok, which version ? latest version is 2.0.0, compile 'com.github.nisrulz:qreader:2.0.0'

Comment: text.post cannot reslove method post :( 
and text.setText cannot resolve method settext :(  nOw these 2?

Comment: i think you are leaner in android better you can download that project from github. run it  then use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142831/discussion-between-magesh-pandian-and-nimra-asad).

Answer (score 0):

This simple alteration in my code worked well to open qr scanner in my code.  Below is the code. If needed by any body.

```
zXingScannerView  = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
zXingScannerView.startCamera();

FrameLayout preview =(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(zXingScannerView);
```